# How to insert multiple records in MySQL with node js also by checking insert when doesn't exist?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I want to insert multiple records in a table also by checking for duplicates, which means to insert only when the record is not present.

I am able to insert a single record by checking for the duplicate. The following contains the single record insertion which worked for me.

```
connection.query(`
    INSERT INTO player_master (player_id,registered_id,registered_id_valid,first_name,middle_name,last_name,email_id,address,city,state,country,zip_code,phone_code,phone_number,email_campaign)
        SELECT * FROM (SELECT 
                        ? AS player_id,
                        ? AS registered_id,
                        ? AS registered_id_valid,
                        ? AS first_name,
                        ? AS middle_name ,
                        ? AS last_name ,
                        ? AS email_id ,
                        ? AS address,
                        ? AS city ,
                        ? AS state ,
                        ? AS country ,
                        ? AS zip_code,
                        ? AS phone_code ,
                        ? AS phone_number ,
                        ? AS email_campaign) AS tmp
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT player_id FROM player_master WHERE player_id = '`+player_id+`'
        )LIMIT 1;`,
            [player_id,registered_id,registered_id_valid,first_name,middle_name,last_name,email_id,address,city,state,country,zip_code,phone_code,
                phone_number,email_campaign]
            ,function (error,result,fields){
                if(error){
                    errorLogger.error("Error creating the registered user in player_master table "+error);
                }else{
                    response.send(JSON.stringify(result))
                }
            });
```

But when I want to insert multiple records I am not able to insert and I am returned with an ERROR. The following code is what I have tried.

```
connection.query(`
    INSERT INTO player_master (player_id,registered_id,registered_id_valid,first_name,middle_name,last_name,email_id,address,city,state,country,
        zip_code,phone_code,phone_number,email_campaign)
        SELECT * FROM (SELECT 
                        ? AS player_id,
                        ? AS registered_id,
                        ? AS registered_id_valid,
                        ? AS first_name,
                        ? AS middle_name ,
                        ? AS last_name ,
                        ? AS email_id ,
                        ? AS address,
                        ? AS city ,
                        ? AS state ,
                        ? AS country ,
                        ? AS zip_code,
                        ? AS phone_code ,
                        ? AS phone_number ,
                        ? AS email_campaign) AS tmp
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT player_id FROM player_master WHERE player_id = ?
        )LIMIT 1;`,
            [temp]
            ,function (error,result,fields){
                if(error){
                    errorLogger.error("Error creating the registered user in player_master table "+error);
                }else{
                    response.send(JSON.stringify(result))
                }
            });
```

I have made the temp as array of data, The temp contains

```
[
  [
    'PID004649ed-86e5-450d-84df-6604501d3a87',
    '12324344',
    'E',
    'Ram',
    'Kalyan',
    'RAO',
    'test@gmail.com',
    'LAKSHMINAGAR LALAPET',
    'SECUNDERABAD',
    'TELANGANA',
    'India',
    '600001',
    '+91',
    '7299426946',
    'false',
    'C4L_PID004649ed-86e5-450d-84df-6604501d3a87'
  ]
]
```

The following is the error which I get when Inserting multiple records.

```
[ERROR] error - Error creating the registered user in player_master table Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '? AS uscf_id,
                        ? AS registered_id_valid,
                        ?' at line 5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **INSERT IGNORE INTO player_master** it does exactly [what you need](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html). In this case you can get rid of your own check. Query results should show how many records were actually inserted.